# EC2 Tomcat instance with Grails app works VERY differently for multipart upload

Tags: tomcat, grails, file-upload, amazon-ec2, multipart

I have a grails app that does a simple multipart upload of a file through the following mechanism:

I have a domain object with a **transient** byte[] field and a multipart form that on submit, goes to a controller that uses request.getFile('name of input form field here').

All this works fine in testing on my local machine, including deploying a war to a tomcat 7 instance on a virtual server that is local.  If I inspect the request in the controller, all is good.

When i put this war up onto a tomcat 7 on an AWS EC2 ubuntu box, everything works fine in the grails app but the file upload.  If I inspect the request (yes, I had intellij hook into the ec2 instance through a firewall hole), the request is a multipart request but has no parts!  No file.  It looks diff than when I inspect it (same code, same intellij setup) locally.

I can find no options in the Amazon tomcat 7 version (yes, they change it some) about what could be doing this.  But my guess is it is either some weird parameter in some config file or some library (I'm going to be diff'ing the libs on the ec2 v. my machines).

Answer (score 0):

Answer discovered!  In order to combat what I'd thought was the problem, I'd set allowCasualMultipartParsing=true in the Context.

Taking that back OUT, solved the problem.  So, I believe this was the case of a bug in my code originally that I tried a bunch of things to fix, and didn't realize I hadn't backed out all my attempts once I'd found the true source.

So beware that allowCasualMultipartParsing.